# How to dispatch jobs to different queue providers in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jobs, amazon-sqs

In my api I am using Redis for caching dispatched jobs from my controllers: This is how my controller looks

```
class FormSubmissionsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param StoreRequest $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function store(StoreRequest $request, FormSubmission $formSubmission)
    {

        JobStore::dispatch($formSubmission, $request->get('tracking_code'), $request->get('form'));

        return response()->json([
            'id' => $formSubmission->id
        ]);
    }
}
```

All is working, and the only change I did to use `redis` it was some config vars in `dot env` file. My question:

In another controller I want to use some of `Amazon SQS`services for queued jobs, any idea how to config queue and how should I dispatch each job to particular queue handler ?

Comment: What Laravel version? You may use "connection" to dispatch to whatever you want.Just open up documentation its all there. Search for "connection".

Comment: Laravel 5.5  @kyslik

Answer (score 2):

You can pick a connection that should be used to dispatch a job with **onConnection()** method:

```
JobStore::dispatch()->onConnection('sqs');
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#dispatching-jobs for more details.

Comment: so If I do not specify onConnection on dispatch method it will run on redis by default right ?

Comment: If you don't specify the connection, the default one will be used, yes.